# Expressing one given vector as a linear combination of two other ones

Tags: linear-algebra

Express $x=[4,5]$ as a linear combination of $a=[1,3]$ and $b=[2,2].$

My answer came as $x=[ 4a - 3(b-2a)] + 5[(b-2a)/4].$ Is my answer correct ?

Comment: You need to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that:

$x = \alpha a + \beta b$
probably you're correct, but fix the expresion

Comment: i did consider it that way..and the values of alpha beta came like that which i wrote.

Comment: To check a proposed solution to an equation, you can just substitute it and compare. There is no need to ask a question about such things.

Answer (score 3):

i don't know if you are familiar with the matrix notation, but this can be written $$\pmatrix{1&2\\3&2}\pmatrix{x\\y} = \pmatrix{4\\5} and \pmatrix{x\\y} =-\frac 14\pmatrix{2&-2\\-3&1}\pmatrix{4\\5}=\pmatrix{1/2\\7/4} $$

that is $$\pmatrix{4\\5} =\frac 12\pmatrix{1\\3} + \frac 74\pmatrix{2\\2}. $$

Answer (score 0):

$$x(1,3)+y(2,2) = (4,5) \Rightarrow x+2y=4\ \ \& \ \ 3x+2y=5$$

The intersection of these two lines is your solution.

$$f(x) = 2-\frac{1}{2}x \ \ \text{and}\  \ g(x) = \frac{5}{2}-\frac{3}{2}x$$

Then setting them equal you have,

$$2-\frac{1}{2}x=\frac{5}{2}-\frac{3}{2}x \Rightarrow 4-x=5-3x \Rightarrow 2x=1 \Rightarrow x=\frac{1}{2}, y=\frac{7}{4}.$$

Hence your solution is $\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{7}{4}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&4\\3&2&5\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&2&4\\0&-4&-7\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&0&(4-7/2)\\0&-4&-7\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1/2\\0&1&7/4\end{bmatrix}.$$
Thus, you should have that $\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{a}+\frac{7}{4}\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{x}$:
$$
(1/2)\cdot\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\end{bmatrix}+(7/4)\cdot\begin{bmatrix}2\\2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1/2&+&7/2\\3/2&+&7/2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}4\\5\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Thus, we see that we can express $\mathbf{x}$ as a linear combination of $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ as follows (as just verified above):
$$
\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{a}+\frac{7}{4}\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{x}.
$$